# Android Application: Separate audio streams for separate headsets

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I am currently trying to figure out an issue related to routing separate audio streams to different headsets simultaneously in my android application.

Basically, what I need is to stream one sound file to a wireless Bluetooth headset and simultaneously stream a different sound file to another headset. The second headset can be either wired or Bluetooth, it doesn't really matter as much.

Has anyone attempted something similar to this, or have an idea of how to go about doing this?

Thanks